# Side-effects-in-computed-properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I want to avoid having side effects in my code, but I don't know how to fix these, does some one can help?

```
    computed: {
        sumarVerduras(){
          this.totalVerduras = 0;
            for( const verdura of this.verduras){
              this.totalVerduras = this.totalVerduras + verdura.cantidad
            } return this.totalVerduras;
        }
      }
```

It work as I want but side effect is there

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Unexpected side effect in "sumarVerduras" computed property (vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties) at src\App.vue:53:7:
  51 |   computed: {
  52 |     sumarVerduras(){
  53 |       this.totalVerduras = 0;
     |       ^
  54 |         for( const verdura of this.verduras){
  55 |           this.totalVerduras = this.totalVerduras + verdura.cantidad
  56 |         } return this.totalVerduras;


error: Unexpected side effect in "sumarVerduras" computed property (vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties) at src\App.vue:55:11:
  53 |       this.totalVerduras = 0;
  54 |         for( const verdura of this.verduras){
  55 |           this.totalVerduras = this.totalVerduras + verdura.cantidad
     |           ^
  56 |         } return this.totalVerduras;
  57 |     }
  58 |   }
```

Comment: Or someone can explain more about these? ‍♂️ 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not edit any Vue component's data in computed property. Here you modify `this.totalVerduras`, which is considered as Vue's component data.

You can change to:

```
computed: {
  sumarVerduras() {
    let totalVerduras = 0;
    for (const verdura of this.verduras) {
      totalVerduras = totalVerduras + verdura.cantidad
    } 
    return totalVerduras;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as well:

```
computed: {
  sumarVerduras() {
      return verduras.reduce((a, x) => a + x.cantidad, 0);
  }
}
```

This method gets rid of totalVerduras variable and the for loop.